# Building Text message and Video Calling Application using Spring boot

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, angular, spring-boot

I would like to create an application using Spring Boot in which i can make Video Call and sharing test messages between 2 users who are registered on my application. I also want to save those videos for future use like if any person want to see those videos in future i should be having that video.

I know node.js as well can make video calling app using WebRTC in node.js but still i'm not sure can i save that videos in WebRTC?

I'm Java Developer know how to create application from scratch but m struggling with Video Calling feature, can any person help ?

Thanks for you reply!

Comment: I don't quite understand your setup. You are using Angular for the Frontend and Spring-boot for the backend, right? If that's the case you wouldn't use node.js (except maybe for development).

Comment: Yes you are rite i want your suggestion i can use Angular + spring boot

Comment: Other options is to use Node.js which is better to choose..?

Answer (score 5):

videochat has 2 dependencies.
*

1. Media transfer ( Browser side, need javascript )
2. Handshake (signaling, nodejs socket.io preferred, PHP, java, .net can be used )

For handshake,
you can use socket.io, signalR, polling, etc.
assume 2 users, A and B
A must know the B exist and available,
this kind of info transferring generally handled by socket.io (nodejs )but you can do it with polling.
After A & B notice each other than A call B. Then you start connecting the peer with browser webrtc support.
However
there is 3 way for media connection between 2 clients.

- Peer to peer
- Sfu
- Mcu

**Peer To Peer**
Only signal between client enough for media handshaking. The client's browser can talk to each other without any media server. Since there is no media server, the stream will be recorded by the client's own browser. You can look at

https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC

**Sfu**
Kurento, ant media, Wowza, frozen mountain, etc are the Selective Forwarding Unit, A publish the stream to the server when B asks for watching this stream, then the B request to the server. If C asks for watching this stream, then C gets the A and B stream as unicast.  All stream servers have different APIs and methods. For Kurento you need to add new Recordenpoint to your existing pipeline. For Wowza you need to transcode the webrtc to the RTMP then Record the stream. For ant media, the recording process can be started automatically.

https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/6.11.0/tutorials/js/tutorial-recorder.html

**Mcu**
A publish to the server, B publishes to the server, C publish to the server. A can get the mixed ( composite view of A B C ) stream and only 1 stream get etc.

As you see webrtc has different features. Kurento has nodejs & java SDK for communication. However, for publish & play streamside, you need to Javascript ( not nodejs ) at the client-side.

Here is a sample text message & video conference using Wowza & ant media.

https://github.com/Lethea/wowza-webrtc-group-call-and-chat

https://github.com/Lethea/ant-server-webrtc-chat-room